# Canonical way to use FormErrors and FormMessages

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

What's the canonical way to use `FormErrors` and `FormMessages` in `Vueform`?

These `reference docs` do not have concrete examples ...

1. https://vueform.com/reference/form-errors
2. https://vueform.com/reference/form-messages

This does not yield any errors or messages in browser (`NOTE`: `Equivalent call from command-lines does yield the errors/messages`) ...

```
<template>
  <Vueform endpoint="https://xxxxx.xx/xxxxx" method="post">
    <TextElement name="name" label="Name" rules="required|max:80" />
    <ButtonElement name="submit" submits> Submit </ButtonElement>
    <template #empty>
      <FormErrors v-if="hasMessages" />
    </template>
  </Vueform>
</template>
```